# Using Gulp.js to run Jasmine tests automatically?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gulp

I have basic Gulp tasks, and the basic Jasmine test runner set up. How do I use Gulp to run my Jasmine tests on a file save and show me the output? Where in the pipeline should Jasmine go?

I'm new to both these libraries and to JS build and unit testing systems generally, so unsure of the issues and best practice and I haven't found anything online that is basic enough for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`gulp.watch`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb), this watches files and does something when a file changes.

You could make a task like this, or simply use the [`gulp.watch`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) in another task.

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('tests/**/*', ['jasmine']);
});
```

Comment: When doing this, files required by the tests are not reloaded when the jasmine task is re-run, so this doesn't actually help; you still have to restart gulp whenever you change a non-test file.

Comment: What version are you using? It should work with this [commit](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-jasmine/pull/5).

Comment: I'm using version 0.2.0, which seems to be the latest

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to run your tests. You need to setup Karma so that will watch your files.

These two parameters you are after :

```
...
singleRun: false,
autoWatch: true,
...
```

THE SCRIPT :

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');
var karmaServer = require('karma').Server;

/**
 * Run the unit tests
 */
gulp.task('test', ['templates'], function () {
    var bowerDeps = wiredep({
        directory: 'src/bower_components',
        exclude: ['exclude_some_thing_you_dont_need'],
        dependencies: true,
        devDependencies: true
    });

    // This will jQuery to the start so that AngularJS won't use jqLite
    bowerDeps.js.unshift('src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');

    var testFiles = bowerDeps.js.concat([
        'src/app/app.js',    // loading the module first to make Karma avoid nomod-errors
        'src/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '.tmp/templates/*.js',     // HTML-templates converted to JS for directives/etc
        'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ]);

    new karmaServer({
        files: testFiles,
        singleRun: false,
        autoWatch: true,
        configFile: __dirname + '/../test/karma.conf.js'
    }).start();
});
```